# Create HTML footer with TCPDF 5.9

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, php-5.3

I am using TCPDF 5.9.157 to create PDFs in my application and I am looking for a way to 
position some HTML content, namely a `<table>` at the bottom of the page.

This is a sample of the HTML is generate in my code:

```
    $html = "<table>";
    $html .= "<tr><td>CODES</td></tr>";
    $html .= "<tr><td>....</td></tr>";
    $html .= "</table>";
```

and this is the TCPDF method i'm using. The problem seems to be it always positions it in the top left of the page, whereas I want it to be positioned in the bottom left.

```
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 100, 0, 0, $html, 0, 0, false, "L", true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting the parameters passed into the function like this seems to do the trick:

`// $pdf is an instance of TCPDF
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 0, false, "L", true);`